# Expand a menu from within a gtoolbar

Tags: r

Is there a way when I click a toolbar button, instead of menubar button,
to have a menu expanded ?

Example:

```
win <- gwindow()

actions <- list(save=gaction("Save",  icon="save"))

toolbarlist <- actions

gtoolbar(toolbarlist, cont=win)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you want, but it seems like either a gcombobox or adding a popup menu to a widget might do what you want. There isn't anything specific in gWidgets to adding such to a toolbar, although if you are working with just one toolkit you could likely hack something in. Feel free to email if you have questions.